# How urlfetch quotas work?

Tags: google-app-engine, urlfetch, gae-quotas

The following quotas are given at [GAE docs](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits):

- request size: 1 megabyte
- response size: 32 megabytes

If my GAE app receives upload file, 1 megabyte quota is applied?
If my GAE app sends (POST) the file to another server with urlfetch, still 1 megabyte is the the limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Imcoming bandwidth quota: Each incoming HTTP request can be no larger than 32MB.

So an HTTP request from a browser directly to your application (suchas uploading a file) cannot exceed 32MB.

> Urlfetch quota: request size 1 megabyte

So you can't POST a request larger than 1MB using urlfetch

If you need to have an outside service process large files from your app; Upload the files into the blobstore, and then post a link to the external service so that it can fetch the file. If you do not control the external service, and their api does not have a method for fetching files via URL, you might have to rethink and maybe send the file to the external service first rather that to your AE app.

Comment: Thanks for this idea for large files - I've been hitting the urlfetch limit for post requests and couldn't for the life of me figure out how to get around it. +1 for you sir.