# Where can I view Google Apps Script quota usage?

Tags: google-apps-script, quota

We make substantial use of Google Apps Script, and today I saw this error:

> UrlFetch failed because too much upload bandwidth was used in Code (gci standalone script):219

I found lots of links to Google Apps Engine quotas, and how to check Apps Engine quota usage. However the Apps Engine quotas all showed as 0 in the Google Cloud developers console. This is not surprising since we don't use Apps Engine, but I was unable to find a similar breakdown for Google Apps Scripts.

Is there one?

On another note, this question: [Are there quotas for incoming requests to a Web App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323979/google-apps-script-quota)

has an answer:

> urlFetch quotas do not apply unless you are making the call to the spreadsheets api v3 directly without spreadsheetApp.

We use UrlFetch to retrieve CouchDB data. I would like to monitor the amount of quota for this service that we use. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: The only quotas for Google Service in Apps Script is found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). You can also find here the tables for limitations. The limits are provided solely to assist you in testing scripts. All limits are subject to elimination, reduction, or change at any time, without notice. For your question about urlFetch quotas, I think this [thread](http://www.lhelper.org/dev/google-appengine-docs-20090422/appengine/docs/quotas.html) and [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971448/how-urlfetch-quotas-work) can help you with that.

Comment: Hi. I am aware that using Apps Engine you can see your quota usage. I am not using Apps Engine, I am using Apps Scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the quota for the send emails quota but don't think you can do it for urlfetch.

Comment: That's helpfully unhelpful