# Quota on Googles External Services

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

I have received this error while using a google sheet. It throws this error on sheets that use the "SheetsFinance" api. Does anybody know how I can view my quota limit for this item?

"You may have hit Google's daily quota limit for external services per user (20,000/day)! (line 1879)."

The other [post forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205874/where-can-i-view-google-apps-script-quota-usage) is different to the other above. I cannot find any references to this error anywhere.

Comment: Only the daily email sent quota has a way to see how much of the Google Apps Script quotas has used. Resource: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas. Are you using a script to make calls to the SheetsFinance API? If so, please provide a [mcve] an rephrase "Does anybody know how I can view my quota limit for this item?" If you are using the SheetsFinance add-on it's very linkely that the question is off-topic here.

Comment: Another resource https://www.sheetsfinance.com/docs/#/?id=quotas

Comment: It's 20k/day. What else do you need to know?

Comment: Thanks for your responses to far. I think this is more of a google app script question rather than a sheets finance. If I run their script, google should be able to tell me how many calls were made or my remaining quota for a specific item. Is this not possible?